# Lumia 950 XL - Inter-country usage

Tags: windows-10-mobile, unlocking, lumia-950-xl

I am planning to buy a Lumia 950 XL at Qatar and use it in India. What are all the thing I should look out for so that I will have minimum trouble when I am using it in India.

Some things which I think I should be careful about.

- Make sure 4GB bands are usable in India.
- Make sure it is not locked to a carrier

Can someone help me out and tell what else should I keep an eye out for ?

Also comment if doing this will be a good idea or should I just buy one in India.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you buy an unlocked phone it doesn't matter whether you buy it in Qatar or India.

The network bands generally used in India are:

- 2G capabilities: GSM 900, GSM 1800
- 3G capabilities: UMTS 2100
- 4G capabilities: LTE 850 (5), LTE 1800 (3), LTE 2300 (40)

Note that 4G is so far only available with Airtel in India, although other carriers are gearing up for a 4G release soon. However, even if your Indian carrier does not have 4G (yet), you can still use the phone for 2G and 3G.

That's all you should keep an eye out for.

Comment: Too late ! I already got one :)

Comment: And how is it? Give us your experience.